# Writing and reading audio from a tempfile.TemporaryFile

Tags: python, audio, temporary-files, pydub

I want to convert an mp3 audio file to a wav file "on the fly":

```
import pydub
audio_segment = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(audio_path)
```

This works:

```
with open("temp.wav", mode="wb") as temp_file:
    audio_segment.export(out_f=temp_file, format="wav")
with open("temp.wav", mode="rb") as temp_file:
    signal_wave = wave.open(temp_file)
    sample_rate = 16000
    signal = numpy.frombuffer(
        signal_wave.readframes(sample_rate), 
        dtype=numpy.int16
    )
```

I thought the `tempfile` module would give me a more elegant way, where I don't need clean up any file. However, there seems to be a problem writing to and then reading from the `TemporaryFile` object:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="wb") as temp_file:
    audio_segment.export(out_f=temp_file, format="wav")
    signal_wave = wave.open(temp_file)
    sample_rate = 16000
    signal = numpy.frombuffer(
        signal_wave.readframes(sample_rate), 
        dtype=numpy.int16
    )
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-785440e73545> in <module>
      4     sample_rate = 16000
      5     signal = numpy.frombuffer(
----> 6         signal_wave.readframes(sample_rate),
      7         dtype=numpy.int16
      8     )

AttributeError: 'Wave_write' object has no attribute 'readframes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Executed in Python 3.9.13, Pydub version 0.25.1, NumPy version 1.23.5

Something like this maybe ?

```
tmp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(dir=".",suffix=".wav")
obj = mp3.export(tmp, format="wav") )
signal_wave = wave.open(obj, 'rb')
sample_rate = 16000
signal = numpy.frombuffer(
    signal_wave.readframes(sample_rate), 
    dtype=numpy.int16
)
```